# adding .json files to an exe file using pyinstaller

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller

I was creating a .exe file from a python file using pyinstaleer and I had to add a .json file to it. I used the  --add-data parameter in many ways but they returned an error

Inp 1: pyinstaller -F --add-data "vocab.json" definition.py
Error1 : pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: 'vocab.json'

Inp 2: pyinstaller -F --add-data "vocab.json;vocab.json" definition.py
Error2: That made the 3 folders- dist, pycache, and build along with the definition.spec and the definition.exe file. But when I ran the exe file, a cmd window opened and I got this error message. [the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rqyr.png) The error was saying that the json could  not be found but it was in the same folder as the python file.

Inp 3 : pyinstaller --add-path ".\vocab.json:."  definition.py
Error 3: pyinstaller: error: unrecognized arguments: --add-path

Inp4: pyinstaller --add-data ".\vocab.json:."  definition.py
Error 4: pyinstaller: error: argument --add-data: invalid add_data_or_binary value: '.\vocab.json:.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pyinstaller documentation (https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options-group-what-to-bundle-where-to-search)  says:

*Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable. The path separator is platform specific, os.pathsep (which is ; on Windows and : on most unix systems) is used. This option can be used multiple times.*

You have to add the platform specific separator. For Windows is ; , for Linux is :.

If you are on Windows, try:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "vocab.json;."
```

If you are on Linux, try:

```
pyinstaller -F --add-data "vocab.json:."
```